# Apply formula on entire column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheets and I want to apply the below formula to entire column leveling only 2 rows from top but somehow I am not able to apply it to column, I am able to apply it to single row and it works.

`=INDIRECT("C" & ROW() - 1)-INDIRECT("B" & ROW())`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using INDIRECT, add the following formula to a cell in the second row

```
=FILTER(C1:C-B2:B,LEN(C1:C))
```

The above formula will automatically fill out the rows where the column C has a value. It assumes that Column B and Column C will have only numeric values.

If necessary, adjust the cell references according to the row where the numeric values starts.